# Using arcpy.Statistics_analysis

Tags: arcpy, statistics

I know that `arcpy.Statistics_analysis` is able to calculate the sum of Float fields. Now I have a gdb named `yyy.gdb` that contains a feature class named `abc` like this:

[image]

where:

- `abc` contains 3 fields `A`, `B` and field `Shape_Area`;
- field `A` contains `A1, A2, A3...`;
- field `B` contains `B1, B2, B3...`.

I want the sum of `Shape_Area` when `A=A1` and `B=B1`, `A=A1` and `B=B2`... i.e. an output table like this:

[image]

```
import arcpy, os, time

print 'start：' + str(time.ctime())
ws = r"F:\data\yyy.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = ws
arcpy.Statistics_analysis('abc', "F:/data/yyy.gdb/abc_1", [["Shape_Area", "SUM"]])
print 'abc is ok'

print 'ok：' + str(time.ctime())
```

Answer (score 1):

To sum the `Shape_Area` relative to the combinations of `A` and `B` fields, it should be:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "F:/data/yyy.gdb"
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("abc", "F:/data/yyy.gdb/stats", [["Shape_Area", "SUM"]], "A,B")
```

where `"A,B"` are the *case_fields*, as described in the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm).
Although, the result will be something like:

```
A B SUM
A1 B1 SUM1
...
An Bn SUMn
```

Instead, what do you want is ["Tabulate Area"](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm), so a good strategy should be to rasterize the layer and apply it.

Comment: Forgive me only to see the reply,thanks for Antonio Falciano,now i know how to deal with my table.
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(abc, temp_1, 'Shape_Area SUM', 'A;B')
arcpy.PivotTable_management(temp1, 'A', 'B', 'SUM_Shape_Area', final)
fianal is what i wanted.

Comment: No problem. You can post your solution as an answer and accept it. Or you can also improve this one.